# How to display the plot.title in top of plot if we are using plot.titile and plot.suptitle together in matlibplot in python

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, plot

How to display the plot title in top of plot if we are using `plot.title` and `plot.suptitle` together in matplotlib in Python?

The given code plot subtitle content to the top of title. I want `plt.title` content first then next line I want `plt.subtitle` content

```
plt.title(typeOfflow[6],size=16)    
plt.suptitle(['N.TCPUp =%s'% typeOfflow[2],'N.TCPDn =%s'% typeOfflow[1],
              'Flow.Type =%s'% typeOfflow[3],
              'NumberofNetflix =%s'% typeOfflow[8]],size=14)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution: Change the title and subtitle and change the `fontsize`.

An example:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = x**2

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.title("spam", fontsize=8)
plt.suptitle("more spam", fontsize=12)
```

[image: example suptitle]

Comment: I want  Spam on TOP then more spam on next line

Answer (score 0):

I just interchanged the contents..
I got result as I expected way..

```
plt.title(['N.TCPUp =%s'% typeOfflow[2],'N.TCPDn =%s'% typeOfflow[1],
           'Flow.Type =%s'% typeOfflow[3],
           'NumberofNetflix =%s'% typeOfflow[8]],size=14)   
plt.suptitle(typeOfflow[6],size=16)
```